# Strategy for wrapping C++ objects with another language - memory management

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, api

I have a C++ library where I want all core logic to happen. I would like to create wrappers for it in different languages (eg. Objective C and Java), which would be the only interface exposed to developers.

The issue I'm facing is the memory management of the wrapper objects.

Consider the C++ object:

```
class Node {
public:
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> children;
  void addChild(std::shared_ptr<Node> node);
}
```

And let's just assume I have a Java object JNode that blindly wraps Node, passing everything through.

```
public void doSomething() {
  JNode node = new JNode();
  someOtherNode.addChild(node);
}
```

When this method returns, the Java object will be destroyed, but the C++ object will have been kept alive by the std::shared_ptr.

Now later on, say I want to iterate through the children of some node. Their corresponding Java objects have been lost, so I need to recreate them on each access. This seems expensive and potentially confusing if the developer has kept references to original Java objects, which are now going to be different.

I've toyed with the idea of caching the Java objects, but this is further complicated by the fact that the C++ side might be creating new nodes, which wouldn't have a corresponding Java object. It also makes the memory management difficult since the C++ side might remove nodes such that there's no remaining references, but the Java cache would keep them alive.

Is there a better/known strategy for handling this kind of use-case?

Answer (score 0):

Happily this has already been solved for you.

http://www.swig.org/

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages. SWIG is used with different types of target languages including common scripting languages such as Javascript, Perl, PHP, Python, Tcl and Ruby. The list of supported languages also includes non-scripting languages such as C#, Common Lisp (CLISP, Allegro CL, CFFI, UFFI), D, Go language, Java including Android, Lua, Modula-3, OCAML, Octave, Scilab and R. Also several interpreted and compiled Scheme implementations (Guile, MzScheme/Racket, Chicken) are supported

Comment: Thanks for the response but I've already tried out SWIG and while it saves having to manually write the wrapper code, it does it in the same naive way as in my example. It's also really clunky when it comes to dealing with smart pointers.

Comment: You don't post much of your code so I can't be sure, but I wonder whether you have a design problem in your tree. If you're getting circular references you might consider using a weak_ptr to hold the back-reference to the parent.

Comment: This is a contrived example to illustrate my problem, but the C++ side is correct. The issue with smart pointers and SWIG is more to do with the fact that it gets exposed via the interface. See: http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/Java.html#Java_smart_pointers

Comment: I don't see a problem if you have annotated swig properly, a jnode wraps a shared_ptr<Node>. If the client keeps a reference it's still valid after adding it to the tree. If not, then yes you'll have to accept the recreation of the JNode wrappers during iteration. This is because your library knows nothing of JNodes.